Dell Alienware x14 ubuntu, Audio output is less than windows os. New to linux what to do
I have been using Linux for a while and audio quality and output is so much worse than in Windows. The machine audio is fascinating in Windows, I love it but i want the same in Linux.

Where windows is sold already installed on your device; it was tailored to take best advantage of the strengths and hide the weaknesses or your device. On a generic install (be it Ubuntu, or a default Microsoft Windows install) none of those tweaks will exist... you need to make them yourself (or download configs from the OEM/maker of your device).  Either way we can't help you, as we don't even know what Ubuntu product/release you're using anyway
